# In-Built Browser Spell Check Not Working

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

I upgraded to Windows 10 whenever MS offered the free update.  I have the autocorrect features turned on in the Typing config section as recommended.

[image]

However, even though this is on, this does nothing in IE 11 even though it is mentioned it will [in this article on Microsoft Answers (says see Section D)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/wiki/ie11-iewindows_10/spelling-correction-and-checking-in-internet/a1321c59-3623-49a2-8fce-388ecc2cb057).

Is there a trick to get this working?  Is there some HTML 5 attribute that also needs to be included for this to work in IE 11 (can't use edge).  Spell check works in Chrome and Firefox (only via right-click menu option), so it seems it's an IE 11 issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried the spellcheck attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_spellcheck.asp

```
<input spellcheck="true">
```

Comment: It does appear that default support is off unless explicitly turned on...  so thanks.  I would have thought it was supported outright; this says it's not supported for inputs by default in a lot of browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck